# Image in DocuSign HTML document not working

Tags: docusignapi

I'm using Docusing php api to create and send documents to sign, but when I try to insert an image (I'm using HTML document) the document show's the signer only a white square with the text:

> The linked image cannot be displayed. the file may have been moved, renamed, or deleted. Verify that the link points to the correct file and location.
>   Of course I check the image link several times, I changed the image to another server, try different formats, etc...
>   Any suggestions??
>   My HTML goes like:

```
return <<<HTML
    <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
            <head>
              <meta charset='UTF-8'>
            </head>
            <body>
            <img style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" src="/documents/logo.png" alt="" width="250" height="100" />
            <p style="font-family: Garamond; text-align: center; font-size: 14pt; line-height: 0.1;"><strong>Document title</strong></p>
```

and then the rest of the document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **only** way to add an image to an htlm source doc used for DocuSign is to include it, inline, within the html. In the same way, any CSS must also be inline.

Use a dataurl with an img tag. It works fine.

Comment: Thanks, I use this site https://www.base64-image.de/ to convert the image and paste it into the src tag.

Comment: @LarryK, I take it this is still the case? HTML files cannot reference a logo or such from a public web server?

Comment: @BeninCA Yes. It's an appsec feature.

Answer (score 1):

If you want an embedded image I would suggest that it's inline in the HTML, or you can use PDF or Word or some other format that doesn't require the other file to be loaded.
the DocuSign system cannot load that file and in any case would "flatten" your HTML into a PDF anyway (unless you use responsive signing).